# Perl how to get PDF word Count

Tags: perl

I got full word count in PDF. But I want to get Pdf word count except header,footer and Folios.
Please help thanks in advance.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CAM::PDF;
use CAM::PDF::PageText;
my $filename = shift;
 my $pdf = CAM::PDF->new($filename);
   my $pageone_tree = $pdf->getPageContentTree(1);
   my $count;
 my $cnt = CAM::PDF::PageText->render($pageone_tree);
 print"$cnt";
```

Comment: Please provide at least a sample PDF file. We don't know what your document looks like.

Comment: I am unable to upload my pdf file. Can you please create yourself a dummy pdf file with header and footer and folios. count only the body content without header and footer.

Answer (score 0):

Provided your document isn't too complicated this will do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use CAM::PDF;

my $file = 'C:\Users\username\Documents\illguts.pdf';

my $pdf = CAM::PDF->new($file);

my $word_count = 0;
for my $pagenum ( 1 .. $pdf->numPages ) {
    my $words_on_this_page =
        scalar split( /\s+/, $pdf->getPageText($pagenum) );
    print "Page: $pagenum $words_on_this_page\n";
    $word_count += $words_on_this_page;
}

print "Total words: $word_count\n";
```

Although there's a caveat that PDFs can be very complicated, and this is a very basic approach. Should give you a starting point though.